# Display subcategories in wordpress, but not in a list

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I need to display the subcategories of of a category on my new website.

My structure is as following:

```
Test1
  - Sub1_1
  - Sub1_2
Test2
  - Sub2_1
  - Sub2_2
```

When I am on the category page of "Test1" I need to display the sub categories ("Sub1_1" and "Sub1_2").
I found the following snippet on the web which does display the sub cat:

```
if (is_category()) {
        $this_category = get_category($cat);
    }
    ?>
    <?php
        if($this_category->category_parent)
            $this_category = wp_list_categories('orderby=id&show_count=0&title_li=&use_desc_for_title=1&child_of='.$this_category->category_parent."&echo=0"); 
        else
            $this_category = wp_list_categories('orderby=id&depth=1&show_count=0&title_li=&use_desc_for_title=1&child_of='.$this_category->cat_ID."&echo=0");

        if ($this_category) { ?> 
            <ul>
                <?php echo $this_category; ?>
            </ul>            
        <?php } ?>
```

But it does this in an unordered list with `<ul>` and `<li>`.

```
<ul>
   <li>Sub1_1</li>
   <li>Sub1_2</li>
</ul>
```

Instead of this list I need to display a div with the sub category title and the corresponding sub cat description (or even better: an excerpt of the description, but for the moment I would be happy to just get the full description).
The layout has to be something like

```
<div class="cat-list">
    <div class="cat-subcat">
       <h2 class="cat-title">Sub1_1</h2>
       <p class="cat-text">Subcat1_1 description</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cat-subcat">
       <h2 class="cat-title">Sub1_2</h2>
       <p class="cat-text">Subcat1_2 description</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I adjust the snippet, that it can be displayed in the way I want to show it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This is based on your answer, but the markup/HTML is based on what you shown in the question.*

### If you just want a flat display of all the category's children

Then all that you need to do is use `child_of` in place of `parent` in your `$args`:

```php
$args = array(
    'orderby'  => 'slug',
    'child_of' => $cat_id, // use child_of
//  'parent'  => $cat_id,  // and not parent
);
```

### If you want a hierarchical display

I.e. The same nested structure that you'd get when using [`wp_list_categories()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/).

Then you can use ***recursive** function calls*.

```php
// In the theme functions file or maybe somewhere in your plugin.
function my_list_cats( $parent = 0, $level = 0 ) {
    $cats = get_categories( [
        'parent' => $parent,
        // other args here
    ] );

    if ( empty( $cats ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    // Just for styling purposes..
    $classes = 'level-' . absint( $level );
    $classes .= $level ? ' cat-child' : '';

    echo '<div class="cat-list ' . $classes . '">';

    foreach ( $cats as $term ) {
        echo '<div class="cat-subcat">';

        echo '<h2 class="cat-title">' . $term->name . '</h2>';

        // Please note that wp_trim_words() will strip all HTML tags.
        if ( $description = wp_trim_words( $term->description, 28 ) ) {
            echo '<p class="cat-text">' . $description . '</p>';
        }

        my_list_cats( $term->term_id, ++$level );

        echo '</div><!-- .cat-subcat -->';
    }

    echo '</div><!-- .cat-list -->';
}
```

Then on a category archive, in the template, just call:

```php
my_list_cats( get_queried_object_id() );
```

And in the function, I used [`wp_trim_words()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_trim_words/) for trimming the category description *by words*, but you can really use your own function for trimming *by characters*. :)

#### Sample output and styling

```css
/* Just some basic styling */

.cat-list { padding: 0 10px }

/* Main/parent category */
.cat-list.level-0 { background: #d4edda; color: #155724 }

/* All child categories */
.cat-list.cat-child { margin-left: 1em }

/* Child/sub categories levels 1 and 2 */
.cat-list.level-1 { background: #fff3cd; color: #856404 }
.cat-list.level-2 { background: #f8d7da; color: #721c24 }
```

```html
<div class="cat-list level-0">
    <div class="cat-subcat">
        <h2 class="cat-title">Foo Child</h2>
        <p class="cat-text">Foo Child description</p>

        <div class="cat-list level-1 cat-child">
            <div class="cat-subcat">
                <h2 class="cat-title">Foo Subchild</h2>
                <p class="cat-text">Foo Subchild description</p>

                <div class="cat-list level-2 cat-child">
                    <div class="cat-subcat">
                        <h2 class="cat-title">Foo Sub-subchild</h2>
                        <!-- No description -->
                    </div><!-- .cat-subcat -->
                </div><!-- .cat-list -->
            </div><!-- .cat-subcat -->

            <div class="cat-subcat">
                <h2 class="cat-title">Foo Subchild 2</h2>
                <!-- No description -->
            </div><!-- .cat-subcat -->
        </div><!-- .cat-list -->
    </div><!-- .cat-subcat -->

    <div class="cat-subcat">
        <h2 class="cat-title">Foo Child 2</h2>
        <!-- No description -->
    </div><!-- .cat-subcat -->
</div><!-- .cat-list -->
```

Answer (score 2):

I've done it this way now and it works, but still might be too complicated or wrong or unusual... if you see any chance to improve the code, please leave a comment as I am new to PHP and WordPress templating at all ...

```
<?php 
  $category_ids = get_all_category_ids(); 
  $current_category = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
  $cat_id = $current_category->cat_ID;
        
  $args = array(
          'orderby' => 'slug',
          'parent' => $cat_id
  );
  $categories = get_categories( $args );
  foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
       echo '<div><h3 class="title">' . $category->name . '</h3><div class="text">' . $category->description . '</div><div class="ink"><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">Read more</a></div></div>';
   }
?>
```

Comment: With this solution, the new problem is, that I'll get the first sub categories. But if there are sub-sub categories (e.g. child categories of Sub1_1, letzts name them Sub1_1_1 and Sub1_1_2), the template does not work anymore... so i still do need help here

Answer (score 2):

For getting ***all nested levels***, you could use `child_of` param.

Then you could build any structure you want with `array_reduce` or with similar approach

```
$category = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
$cat_id   = $category->cat_ID;

$categories = get_categories(
    [
        'orderby'    => 'slug',
        'child_of'   => $cat_id,
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ]
);

$content = array_reduce(
    $categories,
    function ( $content, $category ) {
        ob_start();
        ?>
        <div class="cat-subcat">
            <h2 class="cat-title"><?php echo esc_html( $category->name ) ?></h2>
            <p class="cat-text"><?php echo esc_html( $category->description ) ?></p>
        </div>
        <?php

        return $content . ob_get_clean();
    },
    ''
);

echo sprintf( '<div class="cat-list">%1</div>', $content );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <?php 
          $category_ids = get_all_category_ids(); 
          $current_category = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
          $cat_id = $current_category->cat_ID;
                
          $args = array(
                  'orderby' => 'slug',
                  'parent' => $cat_id
          );
          $categories = get_categories( $args );
          foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
               echo '<div><h3 class="title">' . $category->name . '</h3><div class="text">' . $category->description . '</div><div class="ink"><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">Read more</a></div></div>';

          $subargs = array(
                  'orderby' => 'slug',
                  'parent' => $category->term_id
          );
          $subcategories = get_categories( $subargs );

 foreach ( $subcategories as $subcategory ) {
               echo '<div><h3 class="title">' . $subcategory->name . '</h3><div class="text">' . $subcategory->description . '</div><div class="ink"><a href="' . get_category_link( $subcategory->term_id ) . '">Read more</a></div></div>';
}

           }
        ?>
```